# Apache ECharts logarithmic y-axis do not automatically adjust as well as linear axes. Can the power of the log scale be changed?

Tags: javascript, apache-echarts

Basically, the automatic sizing of the y-axis on Apache ECharts is pretty fantastic on linear y-axis scales. In linear situations the range of the y-axis will be just wider than the data in view. But when I want to use logarithmic scale the data can become quite scrunched up. The example link shows data scrunched into a small area in the vertical middle of the chart.

Is there some setting so the logarithmic y-axis behaves more like a linear axis with regards to the size of its range in relation to the data's range?

I don't want to set the minimum and maximum values of the axis, as some charts have a range finder and automatically update based on what's on screen. I believe hard coding these may screw this up.

Perhaps changing the log power would work, but I can't see anyway to do this in the documentation. A log scale to power of 2 would presumably give an axis range of 512 to 2048 in the example, not perfect, but much better than the 100 to 10000 now. Any other solutions also welcomed.

[Link with code sample here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-log&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQAywA5rAIKkQDOlANEergGYWxKAYxzQwOAE6UiAXy7owwYFkggCqYhgkQ6dSVQjiAtp26xewCUYCGYcRKpJrM2AB4ARhID0APiTuXdSEZaXQ5Ilw9aAATdTM-AUoE0Nhw9FJmNjjNMABPEHxBIVscOktc001oayNCylJK4lYQLENqCGhCpFhWAAtgAHcCXmssVhxU-WJo22sCAG1KRk5BACEVygBhDYARDYBRDYAxDYBxDYAJDYBJSgBdWSm6bVjCTQSqAGYAUkb0bTovUSABZflN0O5gHZgEYvmCzEIYGBrB1qNZ3DgsAQwBIAK44R5EXKZVjZYh5ApULD0P6waq1KgVcGwIwdSwAZRabQ6XTM6D6g2xeIJmhkhP5kggOFJsHmZg0mjpNTqtDoACZaQp8nVWp1NbAZsiFgB2YEcWCm82Wi0ARitdotZotADYrQAOK0ATgeouZCqqyqoqs--opOp5-sNc1lxs-Vqd1uNavjKcdqdNPuIYvQDxkAG4gA)

PS: after trying 3 other JavaScript charting libraries this weekend, Apache ECharts is blowing my mind now. It seems awesome so far.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here to this. The below settings, when set in the `yAxis` options, both sets the log scale to 2 and sets the minimum and maximum values to the minimum and maximum values currently in view (good where the chart is zoomable).

```
min: 'dataMin',
max: 'dataMax',
type: 'log',
logBase: 2,
```